# Best way to set variables from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, ecmascript-6

I have the following code which feels a bit redundant as I'm iterating over the same array many times, any suggestions to improve while keeping it readable would be appreciated.

The array object format is a standard one where I am checking the keys in each object to check it matches a certain condition e.g. every object contains one value, or only some of them do e.t.c  [{},{},{}]

```
const getValue = arrayOfObjects => {

  const hasA = arrayOfObjects.some(
    object => arrayOfObjects.abc === 'val1'
  );

  const hasB = arrayOfObjects.every(
    object => arrayOfObjects.abc === 'val2'
  );

  // the above 2 iterations are repeated about 4 more times for different checks 
  // then there are a few versions of the below assignment depending on the above variables

  const hasC =
    hasA ||
    hasB;

  // finally the function returns one of the values
  if (hasA) {
    return 'val10';
  } else if (hasB) {
    return 'val11';
  } else if (hasD) {
    return 'val12';
  }
};
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to check `A`, then `B`, then `A || B`. Secondly, if you check `every`, then if `hasA` evaluates to `true`, then B will always be `false`

Comment: I think that the actual matters here. Please add it.

Comment: @GalAbra I'm sure there's a better way to do it but I need to know the value of A on its own, B on it's own and C if there is A or B because all 3 would return different values out of the function. Also as I added, there are many more checks that aren't there, I don't have the exact code to share at the moment.

Comment: @OriDrori I don't have the actual, it was an exercise given in a workshop, was more trying to think of better ways to approach the problem.

Comment: This code doesn't make too much sense. Checks properties of the array object (not the current element) inside a loop, creates an unused variable (`hasC`) and references a non-existing variable (`hasD`). It's also unclear to me, what was this code intended to do...

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a theoretical question. It sounds like you're wondering if using a few `Array.prototype` methods like `some` and `every` on the same array over and over has downsides or if there is a more readable way to do it.

It depends.

If the size of the array `n` is generally pretty small, in a practical sense, it doesn't matter. Choose what is more readable. Big O complexity comes more into play on a practical level if you're dealing with a lot of array items.

Boolean vars derived from `some` and `every` can be very readable in my opinion.

If you are in a situation where the array could be quite large, you could consider trying to do it in one step. `Array.prototype.reduce` would be a good tool for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: It was a problem given in a workshop for learning JS and I tried the approach above, I was advised at the end, that there is a more efficient method than iterating over the same array many times. I was just trying to understand what that might be.

I did try a reduce and ended up with an object which has a count of each key that I'm checking. Trying to figure out how to use this object to check for values and then return a variable from it.

Comment: ahh. What are you having trouble with in terms of the object?

Comment: so the object is in the form {a: 3} or {b: 5} or {a: 2, b: 1, c: 3} etc, I'd like to set some variables based on which keys are present in the object, it would be nice to do this in a clean and efficient way, I was looking at a for in loop but don't know if that's the best way.

Comment: Or maybe I could use a switch?

Comment: I would only advise switch if the different conditions represented by the variables are mutually exclusive. If you're creating some sort of table of counts with `reduce`, you can use a handle of boolean expressions to do the same thing as `every` and some. Say `hasA = counts.hasA === asourceArray.length`.You might get more help on the second part of your problem with a new question and posting the code you are working with.

Comment: Thanks I'll post a new question

Answer (score 0):

In general when you're making use of `every` and `some` (which I personally love, as they're very readable), you should stop and think about the necessity of the checks you're making.

To simplify the examples you had, let's say you have a bunch of fruits and you're checking whether:

1. There is at least one orange.
2. All of the fruits are apples.

It's clear that

> If (1) is **true**, then (2) must be **false**

And the other way around:

> If (2) is **true**, then (1) must be **false**

Then you can spare the testing one of them if the other one is `true`, using `else if` for example.
Additionally, if one of them is `false` - then you simply don't have to check `(1) or (2)`, which is guaranteed to be `false`.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. However in the case where some of 1) is true and some of 2) is true and maybe some of 3) is true, I need to know that so I can use them in conditional logic later.

I agree to be explicit as well and using every and some but have been advised there is a better way with less repitition.

I have ended up with an object which counts each type after using a reduce but having a problem trying to use switch with this object to check for cases now.

Comment: Why would you use `reduce` with this counting object? (Which is usually an efficient solution)

Comment: I mean I used reduce on the original array - which gives me an object now of keys with counts in them. I'm trying to find a way to operate on this object to set values.